# Differences in timing between timeit.timeit() and Timer.autorange()

Tags: python, performance, profiling, timeit

I am trying to figure out how to use Python's [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module but I get vastly different timings between its [timeit.timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) method and [timeit.Timer.autorange()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.autorange):

```
import timeit
setup = """
def f():
    x = "-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))
"""

def f():
    x = "-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))


t = timeit.timeit("f()", setup=setup, number=100)
print(t)

num, timing = timeit.Timer(stmt='f()', globals=globals()).autorange()
per_run = timing/num
print(per_run *1000)
```

results in numbers like

```
0.0025681090000944096  # timeit.timeit
0.014390230550020533   # timeit.Timer.autorange
```

so an order of magnitude of difference between the two approaches.

I am probably doing something wrong but have no idea what. The `autorange` documentation is so sparse.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `timeit.timeit` is the total runtime, not per iteration. You need to divide it by the `number`!

This example which uses the number of iterations determined by `autorange` should nicely show it:

```
import timeit

setup = """
def f():
    x = "-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))
"""

def f():
    x = "-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))


iterations, timing = timeit.Timer(stmt='f()', globals=globals()).autorange()
per_run = timing/iterations
print(per_run)

timing = timeit.timeit("f()", setup=setup, number=iterations)
per_run = timing/iterations
print(per_run)
```

Right now it gave me

```
2.2483807100024934e-05
2.0093059600003473e-05
```